# Enhanced precision in the middle of a potentiometer

Tags: arduino, voltage, potentiometer

I am building a flight simulator rig that uses potentiometers to measure the position of various controls. I'm using a 10 bit ADC to read the value of the potentiometer as a fairly basic voltage divider. The problem is that the range of the stick is only about 10% of the range of the potentiometer. Is there a way to read just the voltage of the middle of that range? Otherwise, I'm just losing major amounts of precision, with only 10 discreet values.

The ADC I have is configurable to read MUCH more precisely at lower voltages. Eg, if I can get the "range" down to 0-1V on a 5V supply, it will read with the full 10 bit precision on the 0-1V. So shifting the range is also a viable option. I have a 16 bit ADC on the way, but would love to retain the full range instead of just abusing the extra precision and discarding the wide range.

It has been 15 years since I was in college messing with this stuff (and forgot how much I loved it), so I'm very rusty.

Comment: Enhancing sensitivity may be as simple as a providing gain with a midpoint reference using a non-inverting op amp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFKvsz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Adjust trimpot R9 to get the output voltage just above 0V with the minimum usable setting on the input R8. The gain is 100K/R2 = 33.3, so the output will be from (say) 200mV to 3.5V for the input from R8 from 2-3V. You can change R2 if you like. If you want to change the lowest input from 2V to something else, you'll probably have to change R1/R11 and maybe R9. It has to allow the input to be adjusted just a bit below the minimum usable input from R8.

Single 5V supply is okay. The LM324 has 4 amplifiers, so this is one 14-pin package plus 9 resistors plus a trimpot.

This circuit is a textbook "instrumentation amplifier" configuration, made from the least expensive op-amps available and with an adjustable trim on the zero.

Note that if you use a differential-input ADC you may be able to just feed the inputs shown left of OA1/OA2 directly into the ADC, so no additional active components.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading something (quite possible, given the hour...), you've just made an in-amp out of the three op-amps, right? Why not just use an in-amp instead and cut down on the component count?

Comment: @Hearth Certainly possible. A modern 5V instrumentation amplifier (especially one with zero drift) would be "better" in most ways, but maybe an inconvenient package and this 10 cent amplifier will likely do the job. You'd still need the R9/R10/R11 chain and would have to make sure it doesn't saturate.

Comment: Could be worth mentioning that if *both* potentiometers were installed close to each other, but far from the amplifier electronics, there would be excellent rejection of noise in the differential signal lines, dispite the distance. I do like this idea.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. A bit complicated but I think I can make this work. :)